# Remove punctuation java

Tags: java, string, char

I'm trying to remove punctuation from a string but keep the spaces, as I need to be able to distinguish different words. The end goal is to find the length of each word in a string.

I set up a `for` loop to check the length of a word until it hits a space but this would count the punctuation as a letter. I know that I would have to change the variable in the if statement to reflect the length of the substring between `i` and the `indexOf` the space in the string.

```
for(int i=0; i > stringLength - 1;){
original.substring(i, original.indexOf(' '));
if(i > minLength)
```

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to do? Do you want to remove the punctuation and get the length of string?

Comment: I have to get the length of each word within a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it might be tempting to throw a bunch of fors and ifs, it would be cleaner to just use a regular expression:

```
Pattern.compile("[.,; ]+").splitAsStream(input)
```

A full example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Counting {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String text = "This is a string. With some punctuation, but I only care about words.";

        String wordsWithLengths = Pattern.compile("[.,; ]+")
                .splitAsStream(text)
                .map(word -> word + " => " + word.length())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        System.out.println(wordsWithLengths);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This => 4
is => 2
a => 1
string => 6
With => 4
some => 4
punctuation => 11
but => 3
I => 1
only => 4
care => 4
about => 5
words => 5
```

Also, if you want to count how many words have more than N characters you can:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CountingWords {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String text = "This is a string. With some punctuation, but I only care about words.";

        int threshold = 5;
        long amountOfWords = Pattern.compile("[.,; ]+")
                .splitAsStream(text)
                .filter( word -> word.length() > threshold)
                .count();

        System.out.println("There are " + amountOfWords +  " words with more than " + threshold + " characters");
    }
}
```

Comment: consider `\W` to match all non-word characters

Comment: I didn't add `\W` because it would also include valid characters like `ñ` or `á`  on other languages.

Comment: I'm having trouble compiling it, could you help me out by using the variables I used because I'm not to sure what goes where :

Comment: Which part? The regexp is intended for strings, but you could use a `collect` or `reduce` for partitioning arrays in a similar fashion.

Comment: I have it to where String original is for user input, String altered is anything that is changed through the course of the code (aka wordsWithLengths). I'm not sure how to set it up the way you have, when I do altered = Pattern.compile("[.,; ]+"); it says "pattern can not be resolved" and the .map says its undefined for type String. I don't have any arrays as of now. Sorry, I'm new to code.

Comment: My answer does an intensive use of Java8 features. It seems you either jave other version of java or didn't add the imports. I'm editing my answer with imports just in case.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and a JDM I downloaded from the website two months ago. I should be able to just attach the String altered behind the .splitAsStream(original) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I edited my answer with some imports. Add those to your file and check that your eclipse is se to language level 8 on `
Windows>Preferences>Java>Compiler>compiler compliance level`

Comment: I only have "Building" "Errors/Warnings" "Javadoc" and "Task Tags" under that Java>Compiler subdivision and I'm still receiving errors, like "type mismatch: cannot convert from Pattern to String"

Comment: Did you try with my full example? It sounds like you are trying to assign the compiled Pattern to the string. This is a single line that returns a string: `Pattern.compile("[.,; ]+").splitAsStream(text).map(word -> word + " => " + word.length()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));`

Comment: Cool! Don't forget to choose my answer or vote it if it was of help.

Comment: One last thing is there a way to compare the lengths of these strings to a given int so that a count is set up to count how many words are longer than the int? I can set up the count I just need to know how to reference the size of the word to the int, I tried if(word.length > minLength) but it had an error

Comment: I just updated the answer, hope it helps. Check [this post about java 8 collections](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/) if you want to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just get length of each word than this will do, otherwise you have do that opertaion in if statment:

```
int cnt = 0;
for(int i=0; i < original.length();i++){
   if(",;:.?! ".indexOf(orignal.charAt(i)) > -1){
       if(cnt > 0){
          System.out.println(cnt);
          cnt = 0;
       }
   } else {
       cnt++;
   }
}
```

Comment: why use `indexOf` instead of `contains`?

Comment: incase you what to know to which it matched, both are same techically

Comment: If you're going to post code please, do your best to post code that doesn't contain errors within it. For example, is the variable named 'original' within the FOR loop an Array?. If not then it should really be: original.length(). And what is this indexof() method? I always thought it was the indexOf() method ;)

Comment: It isn't an array, it's a String. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes it is a string,  there were few mistakes I have fixed those